# how to set kinematic body type in quickbox2d?

Tags: actionscript-3, box2d

In box2d creating a kinematic body is straightforward:

bodyDef.type=b2Body.b2_kinematicBody;

I can't for the life of me work out how to do this using quickbox2d, either when initialising a new quickbox2d object, or referencing the property directly?

any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

In the original Box2D AS, the b2Body.b2_kinematicBody is just a static variable referencing a unique integer. The unique integers are as follows:

```
b2_staticBody = 0;
b2_kinematicBody = 1;
b2_dynamicBody = 2;
```

I am unfamiliar with the Box2D wrapper you're using, but I would hazard a guess that you could just pass the arbitrary integer straight to your b2BodyDef:

```
/* assuming your quick object is stored in the variable 'myQuickObject' */

myQuickObject.bodyDef.type = new uint(1);

/* you may or may not need to type-cast the integer as uint */
```

Seeing as you can access the original b2BodyDef object through the QuickObject.bodyDef route, you should be able to just alter the type to the necessary integer.